# Where can I use Laravel Facade aliases?

Tags: laravel, facade, laravel-facade

I have built a Laravel 5.4 application with a custom facade, `App\Facades\Repo`.  The Repo facade proxies to a `RepositoryFactory` class. In my app configuration I have an alias `Repo` which points to the Repo facade.  I use it to get repositories with calls such as `Repo::get('User')`.

This works fine if I am in a controller or the routes file.  In other parts of the application however, I can't use the `Repo` alias.  The interpreter looks for a Repo class in the current namespace, and errors out.  This raises two questions:

- Which classes are aware of the facade aliases?  What defines them?
- In classes that are not aware of facade aliases, should I go ahead and import the facade class itself?  Or is this a code smell?

By way of example, classes which are not alias-aware include my repositories themselves.  I have created a super-type for them, but they don't inherit from any Laravel class.  Sometimes my repositories need to call on other repositories to do their work.

Answer (score 1):

What I noticed so far (working with Laravel 5.2) is that when you are inside a namespaced context you need to either have `use Repo;` or precede the facade with a slash, like `\Repo::get("User")`.

Out of a namespaced context, like in `routes.php`, config files, or views, the facade works directly.

But this has more to do with how PHP works than with Laravel itself.